# PHP Script rename folders

Tags: php, rename

I tried fixing this code I found and got it far working but theres a thing
that isn't working at the moment, would anyone have an idea?

```
<?php
$oldname = 'test/19481.81642';

$old_dir_name = substr($oldname, strrpos($oldname, '/') + 1);

$new_dir_name = str_replace($o, 'O', $old_dir_name);

$newname = 'test/19481.' . rand(11111, 99999);

rename($oldname, $newname);
?>
```

This code does work and it renames the folder:
11111.11111 to 11111.5randomnumbers

5randomnumbers = 5 random numbers generated with rand(11111, 99999);

What i want this script to do is rename all folders named:
11111.*
To be renamed to; 
11111.5randomnumbers

Comment: Use a [glob](http://php.net/glob) to get an array of the files, then just iterate over this array with a ```foreach```, and place your code inside the loop so it can be applied to every single file found.

Comment: I have tried but couldn't get it to work, never used glob before also.
Could u give it a try maybe? :s

Comment: Nvm got it to work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$files = glob("test/19481.*");
foreach($files as $file){

$newname = 'test/19481.' . rand(11111, 99999);

rename($file, $newname);//rename file
}
?>
```

Got it to work with the above code!
Thanks to @Avalanche